# What is the tool used to generate the statement SVG images on the SQLite documentation site?

Tags: images, tools, svg

The [SQLite documentation website](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) shows statements as in the following screenshot:

[image]

What is the library/tool used to generate those SVG images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [www.sqlite.org/faq.html](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q25) answers this for you:

> ## (25) How are the syntax diagrams (a.k.a. "railroad" diagrams) for SQLite generated?
>
> Each diagram is hand-written using the [Pikchr](https://pikchr.org/) diagramming language. These hand-written specifications are converted into SVG and inserted inline in the HTML files as part of the documentation build process.
> Many historical versions of the SQLite documentation used a different process for generating the syntax diagrams. The historical process was based on Tcl/Tk and is described at http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/21708. The newer Pikchr-based syntax diagrams first landed on trunk on 2020-09-26.

Comment: Excellent. I did a few searches but without the correct terms, I guess Google did not get it... Thank you.